# How to use WHEN on the following occasion?

Tags: word-usage

When I lived in there, I got to know John

When I was living in there, I got to know John.

While I was living in there, I got to know John.

While I lived in there, I got to know John.

I have been long confused by the usage of when and while,
and I'm not sure whether the four sentences are totally correct.
Please explain in detail, thanks!

Comment: All four subordinators can work in your sentences, but, unless you are referring to prison or a box, you probably ought to say "living there" or "lived there".

Comment: Beautiful. And, of course, we'd use the locative 'there' rather than 'in there' even when responding to someone who's just asked 'Did you meet any of the Murgatroyds when you were in the Sahara?'

Answer (score 1):

Both "when" and "while" introduce [adverbial clauses of time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause). That is, they express time relative to some action. The difference between them is the duration of the time. BUT there is some overlap.

**Both "when" and "while" introduce actions of a long or continuing duration**. They introduce a verb that takes some time to complete or continues for an indeterminate amount of time. For example, both conjunctions would appropriately introduce the following actions:

> she sang
>
> I cooked
>
> he was eating

In contrast, **only "when" introduces actions of short, usually momentary, duration**. You would appropriately use "when" with the following actions that take a short time to complete:

> I stood up
>
> we met
>
> he sneezes

In combination with another clause, **"When" introduces an action that serves as a short interruption of a longer action or shows a sequence of two short actions that happen in immediate succession, and "while" introduce actions of long duration that occur simultaneously**. (There is some overlap of "when/while" here. I'll get there.)

### It's Best to Think About This in Clock Time

Appropriate "when" clauses:

> When I stood up, the fire had reached the doorway.

- The fire occurred from: 7:20:12-7:59:08 (ongoing event)
- I stood up at 7:29:14 (short interruption)

> When I stood up, the music stopped.

- I stood up at 7:29:14 (happened first, momentary)
- The music stopped at 7:29:18 (happened immediately after, also momentary)

Appropriate "while" clauses:

> While the band played, the people were talking.

- The band played: 7:20-8:30 (of longer duration and occurs simultaneously with the second action)
- The people were talking: 7:20-8:00 (of long duration and occurs simultaneously with the first action)

Or,

> While the band played, I slept.

- The band played: 7:20-8:30
- I slept: 7:25-8:15

This is where the overlap occurs! Because "when" can also introduce actions of long duration. So, it is appropriate to say:

> When the band played, I slept.

However, **"while" better stresses the duration**. So, if that's your intention, use "while".

There is one **exception** where we prefer "when" when referring to duration, and that's when speaking about a person's age. So,

> When I was 14, I rode dirt bikes.

and not

> While I was 14, I rode dirt bikes.

---

Returning to the sentences in question,

> When/While I lived/was living there, I got to know John.

**Both "when" or "while" can be used because you are referring to two actions that imply a long duration, and both "when" and "while" can be used in that instance. You can delineate between the two based on whether or not you want to stress the duration.**